# geom_bar counts group and not number of cases

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

So I'm quite new to R and since googling and browsing questions on here did not help me so far, I decided to write mine down.

For descriptive statistics I would like to have a geom_bar Plot. My data frame consists of 21 IDs and each of them has one or more diagnosis. The IDs are obviously numbers from 1 to 21, the diagnosis is coded as 0 and 1 (no and yes). The code I have so far is plotting bars next to each other, but instead of counting the number of cases per group, it plots the number of people per group. So for each diagnosis I have two bars which always represent the number of people per group (attempters vs. non-attempters) and not the number of cases.

My old data frame looks something like this:

| code | MDD | Anxiety | PTBS | age | attempters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 53 | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 32 | 0 |
| 04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 60 | 0 |

but with a lot of columns I don't actually need for my thesis.

At first I changed my data from wide to long and included only columns I need:

```
df_long <- data_gesamt %>%
  select(code, MDD, Anxiety, PTBS, attempters) %>%
  group_by(code, attempters) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = predictors,
                value = severity,
                MDD, Anxiety, PTBS) %>% 
  mutate(attempters = as.factor(attempters)) %>% 
  drop_na(attempters)
```

which got me a data frame as follows:

| code | attempters | predictors | severity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | MDD | 0 |
| 02 | 0 | MDD | 1 |
| 03 | 0 | MDD | 0 |
| 04 | 0 | MDD | 0 |
| 01 | 1 | Anxiety | 1 |
| 02 | 0 | Anxiety | 1 |
| 03 | 0 | Anxiety | 0 |
| 04 | 0 | Anxiety | 1 |
| 01 | 1 | PTBS | 1 |
| 02 | 0 | PTBS | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | PTBS | 1 |
| 04 | 0 | PTBS | 0 |
| 01 | 1 | age | 17 |
| 02 | 0 | age | 53 |
| 03 | 0 | age | 32 |
| 04 | 0 | age | 60 |

and then used the following to plot:

```
plot <- df_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = attempters, fill = attempters)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(.~ predictors) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")

plot
```

I would need to have a count of how many people with MDD, Anxiety and PTBS I have per group and the mean of the age (I could leave this one out though). So far I get the number of people per group (non-attempters vs. attempters) ...
What am I missing or what is wrong?

[image: I would expect something for this. Two bars per group per disorder with the amount of people per group and disorder on the y-axis]

Comment: where is `Alcoholuse` column

Comment: ohh should be PTBS, I will just edit it. thanks!!

Comment: Can you show what you expect as output dataset

Comment: If I do the grouping by code, attempters and predictors, the number of observations is 1

Comment: Do you need `data_gesamt %>% pivot_longer(cols = MDD:PTBS, names_to = 'predictors', values_to = 'severity', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% group_by(attempters = factor(attempters), predictors) %>% summarise(Count = sum(severity), age = mean(age), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: i tried adding a photo but seems that I can‘t .. I would expect a bar per group per diagnosis on the x-axis, the amount of people on the y-axis.

Comment: it depends on what your input is going into ggplot.  Can you check the previous code I posted as comment and see if that is the count and mean you expect

Comment: it still shows me the amount of people per group. I will try to add the photo of it in my post

Comment: It would be better to show the expected output for the data you showed

Comment: just added what i would expect as a photo

Comment: This gets me similar plot `data_gesamt %>% pivot_longer(cols = MDD:PTBS, names_to = 'predictors', values_to = 'severity', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% group_by(attempters = factor(attempters), predictors) %>% summarise(Count = sum(severity), age = mean(age)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = attempters, y = Count, fill = predictors)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')`

Comment: this worked!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Updated: revised the part that mistaken the nature of the data]***

It is recommended to summarize the data before you graph it so ggplot only deal with the visualization of data instead of some additional calculation. In addition to that, you can also double check if the stat calculated is what you want instead of leave it all to ggplot to do all the calculation behind the scene.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# dput of your original table
df <- structure(list(code = 1:4, MDD = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Anxiety = c(1L, 
  1L, 0L, 1L), PTBS = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), age = c(17L, 53L, 32L, 
    60L), attempters = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
  class = "data.frame")

# Calculate the number per predictor & attemp
graph_data <- df %>%
  # pivot the data and only keep records with identified 
  # predictors has value as 1
  pivot_longer(cols = MDD:PTBS,
    names_to = "predictors", values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  # I convert attempers to factor as it only 0 and 1
  # Numeric value confusing with ggplot a bit
  group_by(predictors, attempters = factor(attempters)) %>%
  summarize(severity = n(),
    mean_age = mean(age), .groups = "drop")

# data after summarized
graph_data
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   predictors attempters severity mean_age
#>   <chr>      <fct>         <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 Anxiety    0                 2     56.5
#> 2 Anxiety    1                 1     17  
#> 3 MDD        0                 1     53  
#> 4 PTBS       0                 1     32  
#> 5 PTBS       1                 1     17
```

#### Here is the plot output

```r
# and now plot is taking in graph_data
ggplot(data = graph_data) +
  # I prefer to do the mapping per geom instead of at ggplot call.
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(
    x = attempters,
    # here y value is the sum of severity calculated earlier
    y = severity,
    # when do fill/colors I prefer to explicit specify the group even if it
    # can be auto by ggplot
    fill = attempters, group = attempters),
    # Here stat is identity instead of default count
    stat = "identity", 
    # position_dodge for avoid bar stacked on each other
    position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_grid(.~ predictors) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data_gesamt %>% pivot_longer(cols = MDD:PTBS, names_to = 'predictors', values_to = 'severity', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% group_by(attempters = factor(attempters), predictors) %>% summarise(Count = sum(severity), age = mean(age)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = attempters, y = Count, fill = predictors)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```